# Assembly x64 getcwd() Not Outputting

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I've just started learning/using Assembly x64 on Linux, and am trying to call `getcwd()` with `call`. After attempting to call the `getcwd()` function, I am also trying to output the result which is not working and I do not understand why. Any pointers/help would be really appreciated. Sorry if its a stupid question. I've looked online for examples but haven't found any that help me specifically. Many thanks. Here is the code:

```
section .text
        global _start

extern getcwd

_start:
        mov     rdi,rbx
        mov     rsi,128

        call getcwd wrt ..plt

        mov     rax,1
        mov     rdi,1
        mov     rsi,rbx
        mov     rdx,128

        syscall

        mov     rax,60
        mov     rdi,0

        syscall
```

I compile with:

```sh
nasm -f elf64 -o file.o file.asm
gcc -nostdlib -v -o file file.o -lc
./file
```

And nothing is shown

Comment: Where does `rbx` point?  You don't seem to have allocated any memory for the buffer.

Comment: You are using `rbx` without initialization. Also, if you intend to use c library better stick to `main`, don't use `syscall` and omit `-nostdlib`.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not using the return value of ```getcwd()``` however. ```getcwd``` writes to a buffer and i disregard the return value which is why i overwrite rax. hope this helps and sorry if ive missed something

Comment: @fuz No problem and thanks for the compliment! I've only just started with assembly so im not sure how to allocate memory for the buffer properly/in the best way? I've been reading some tutorials on it but there is no information about that on it really. Just examples which is frustrating. Thanks for the reply

Comment: malloc() and friends, just like in C.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot how getcwd worked. Since you didn't pass it a pointer to a buffer, I assumed it must return a pointer to some static memory.  But no, it's just a wrapper around a system call; that's why it can fail with `-EFAULT` (same as your manual `write` syscall) instead of segfaulting so you can just see nothing.

Comment: The first google hit for `site:stackoverflow.com assembly buffer` is [How do I use a buffer in an Assembly procedure?](//stackoverflow.com/q/13468991).

Comment: BTW, `gcc -nostdlib -lc` is weird.  You can use `gcc -nostartfiles` which is equivalent (except it leaves in libgcc, in case you linked any C that called any libgcc helper functions, e.g. for 128-bit multiply or divide.  Since you don't, there's no difference whether you give -lgcc to the linker or not.)  But generally don't call libc functions from `_start` unless you understand exactly why it works (dynamic linker tricks let glibc initialize itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation that allocates space on the stack. I also switched to `main` and `puts`:

```
global main
extern getcwd
extern puts

main:
        sub rsp, 128+8  ; buffer + alignment
        mov rdi, rsp
        mov rsi, 128

        call getcwd wrt ..plt
        call puts wrt ..plt

        add rsp, 128+8
        ret
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
        mov     rdi,rbx
        mov     rsi,128

        call getcwd wrt ..plt
```

is equivalent to C code `getcwd(__undefined__, 128);`, where `__undefined__` is some value that happens to be in `ebx` on entry to `_start`. On my system it appeared to be `NULL`, which to `getcwd` signalizes that no buffer is passed (regardless of its size being 128).

The `getcwd` function then returns pointer to the newly-allocated buffer (as an extension to POSIX, see `man 3 getcwd`). Your subsequent `mov     rax,1` overwrites this address with the system call, and subsequent instructions pass the value in `ebx` as the buffer to the `write` syscall. Since it was `NULL` before, by the calling convention it remains such, and you call `write(1,NULL,128);`, which returns `EFAULT` and writes nothing.

Comment: Awesome explanation. I understand and this really helped to look at - thank you

Comment: In a statically-linked executable, RBX will be NULL at the top of `_start` under Linux.  But yes, it also happens to be true on x86-64 GNU/Linux after ld.so runs, for PIE or non-PIE.  Various other regs happen to be non-zero, but RBX happens to be 0.